# Using SpringBoot with Neo4J: Updating node creates duplicate node

Tags: java, spring-boot, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

I am trying to update a node on Neo4J, but what ends up happening is that it creates a duplicate Node. I read that the update has to be in a single transaction and I added @Transactional, but still same result. Here is what I have. I tried the approach of reading and deleting the old node, and saving the new one and it appears to be working.  But, I think that is not the right approach.  Why the @Transactional annotation not working.  Thank you.

```
@EnableNeo4JRepositories(com.example.graph.repo)
@EnableTransactionManagement
@org.springframework.contect.annotation.Configuration
public class Neo4JConfig {
   @Bean
   public Configuration configuration() {
       Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
       cfg.driverConfiguration()                 
       .setDriverClassName("org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.http.driver.HttpDriver")
       .setURI("http://neo4j:neo4j@localhost:7474");
       return cfg;
    }

    @Bean 
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory() {
       return new SessionFactory(configuration(), "com.example");
    }

    @Bean
    public Neo4jTransactionManager transactionManager() {
       return new Neo4JTransactionManager(sessionFactory());
    }
}

@Service
public class UserService{
   @Autowired
   UserRepository userRepository;

   @Transactional
   public void updateUser(User user) {
       User existingUser = userRepository.getExistingUser(user.getUserName());
       if(existingUser != null ) {
           user.setSomeValue(existingUser.getSomeValue());
           userRepository.save(user);
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring AOP uses JDK Proxy mechanism by default. It means that you must invoke `@Transactional` method via interface method.

So you should split your service into interface `UserService` and implementation (say `UserServiceImpl`), autowire the interface into the code where you currently autowire the impementation, and then invoke transactional method via interface.

P.S. Another approach is to force Spring to use CGLIB as long as this mechanism is not limited to interfaces. More details for both mechanisms https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch08s06.html

Comment: I updated the code as you suggested.  However, I am still getting the duplicate node when I save.  I added the UserService interface and annotated it with 'Service.  In the controller, I autowired the UserService. I had to add Component annotation to the UserServiceImpl.  Is there anything else that I might be doing wrong.

Comment: Not sure if it is relevant, but the node to be updated already have some relationships. Thanks for the help.

Comment: The above suggestion did work. I was saving the user instead of the existingUser in the above code.  Once I fixed that, and with the suggestion from Nicholay it works.